# Is it possible to set multiple Input streams for Kinesis Analytics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have 3 mongodb collections (from Same Database) which are act as input source. Currently I'm useing 3 kinesis streams to access these collections. I need to analyze them by combining them. Can I use Kinesis Analytics to do this? Because i can't see an option to select multiple streams as inputs for Kinesis Analytic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinesis Analytics does not have the feature to add more than one streaming source and one reference data source as yet.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/limits.html

Comment: Yes it is (AWS Sport team also confirm it). Do you know any way to combine Kinesis streams or any way to overcome my situation?

Comment: Since the documentation for Limits for Kinesis Analytics - "Each application can have one streaming source and up to one reference data source." I believe if you are referring to multiple destinations - that can be done using CLI/SDK (not possible through the console). Coming to your use-case, I don't know of any direct way to do this, but there can be potential workarounds.

Comment: [1] You can send either push data to just one stream and then use Kinesis Analytics InApp Streams to filter records/collection data. [2] add another stream (let's say AllCollectionsStream ) while pushing records to the stream add a logic in your producer to push each record to individual stream + AllCollectionsStream

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Drools Kinesis Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B075MDR5DC), which supports multiple input streams